# How can I provide a consistent user experience for embedded videos from different websites?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I'm creating a website with embedded videos from sites such as `YouTube` and `Twitch`. While the embedded videos function properly, they look vastly different form one another (e.g. they have different themes, sliders, etc.).

I was wondering if it was possible to create a consistent look & theme in embedded videos from a wide array of sites?

I don't really care if the videos are branded to my site, I only want all the embedded videos to look the same. Thanks!

Comment: unless you host the content yourself and use the same player across all the content you won't be able to do this. YouTube, Vimeo, etc use different players/branding (and advertising models etc) and are not big fans of just being used to pay for the hosting/streaming